# Почему strstr выдает ошибку?

Tags: php

```
foreach($masivcheg1 as $index => $val){
    echo strstr($fla, $val);
}
```

Помогите, пожалуйста. Работает все правильно, но выдает еще ошибку

> `Warning: strstr() [function.strstr]: Empty delimiter in`

Comment: А кто такой `$fla`? :)

Comment: `$fla = '1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|';
$val = цифры от 1 до 7`

Answer (score 5):

У вас `$val` - пустая строка отсюда и это предупреждение, вот более простой пример приводящий к аналогичной ошибке:

```
echo strstr("asdf","");
```

Вот такой код будет работать:

```
$masivcheg1 = array('1','2','3','4','5','6','7');

$fla = '1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|';

foreach($masivcheg1 as $index => $val)
{
    echo strstr($fla, $val);
}
```

Если у вас в $masivcheg1 - цифры (целочисленный тип, т.е. `$masivcheg1 = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)`), то необходимо заменить строку "`echo strstr($fla, $val);`" на "`echo strstr($fla, (string)$val);`"